# UpSetR error when using queries: replacement has 1 row, data has 0

Tags: r, upsetr

I have tried to use UpsetR to visualize the input file which can be found [here](https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/s/OupXC8rF2bDFtRV)

```
> library("UpSetR")
> orthogroups_df<- read.table("orthogroups.GeneCount.tsv",  header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
> #All species
> selected_species <- colnames(orthogroups_df)[2:(ncol(orthogroups_df) -1)] 
> selected_species
 [1] "Atha" "Cann" "NQLD" "Natt" "Ngla" "Nlab" "Nsyl" "Ntab" "Ntom" "Slyc" "Stub" "Vvin"
> head(orthogroups_df)
  Orthogroup Atha Cann NQLD Natt Ngla Nlab Nsyl Ntab Ntom Slyc Stub Vvin Total
1  OG0000000    0    0  965    0    0    3    0    0    0    0    0    0   968
2  OG0000001    0    1    3    0    0  448    0    0    0    0    0    0   452
3  OG0000002    0    1  313    0    0  120    1    0    1    0    0    0   436
4  OG0000003    0   93   15   21   46   16   33   63   36   25   39   26   413
5  OG0000004    1   42    2   34  109    6    8  154   11    9    4    0   380
6  OG0000005    0    2   61    1   34   44   91   70   43   20    1    0   367
> ncol(orthogroups_df)
[1] 14
> orthogroups_df[orthogroups_df > 0] <- 1
> upset(orthogroups_df, 
+       nsets = ncol(orthogroups_df), 
+       sets = rev(c(selected_species)), 
+       queries = list(list(query = intersects, params = list("NQLD", "Nlab", "Nsyl"), color = "#238c45", active = T),
+                 list(query = intersects, params = list("NQLD", "Nlab"), color = "#ffd977", active = T)))


Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "freq", value = 45L) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

How is it possible to fix the above error?

Comment: Difficult to answer without knowing what `orthogroups_df` looks like. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format, or a link to the TSV file.

Comment: I updated my question but the whole dataset can be found [here](https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/s/OupXC8rF2bDFtRV).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to set the number of intersects - *nintersects* - to a higher number so that sets in query *params* can be shown.

By default *nintersects* is set to 40, and `list("NQLD", "Nlab", "Nsyl")` appears after 40 at 90th position, so we need a bigger number, here I tried with 90:

```
upset(orthogroups_df, 
      nsets = ncol(orthogroups_df), 
      sets = rev(c(selected_species)), 
      nintersects = 90,
      queries = list(
        list(query = intersects,
             params = list("NQLD", "Nlab", "Nsyl"),
             color = "red",
             active = TRUE),
        list(query = intersects, 
             params = list("NQLD", "Nlab"), 
             color = "blue", 
             active = TRUE)))
```

[image]